# Reference to the random seed in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, montecarlo, random-seed

I am writing a code in Matlab for a model that is aimed to calculate several aggregate outcomes such as total investment and total productivity. In order to show that the result obtained is not a matter of a random seed I need to run Monte Carlo simulation. I know how to fix seeds in Matlab but I do not know how to run Monte Carlo, for example with M=200, so that I can easily refer to the value of the random seed in results of which I am interested?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Could you rephrase the last sentence? Do you need help on how to run Monte Carlo simulations or on accessing the current random seed with which the simulation was initialised?

Answer (score 0):

To run a Monte Carlo simulation that you could reproduce at a later date if needed, you simply need to capture the state of the random number generator at the beginning of each iteration:

```
for mcIteration = 1:200
   rngSeed(mcIteration) = rng;

   %# your code here
end
```

with `rng(rngSeed(i))` you can restore the generator to any seed you want to reproduce.